# uncaught exception: out of memory in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, google-visualization

3 issues I am facing are

Uncaught Exception : out of memory (in firefox)
randomly Failed to load resource: The request timed out.
Even if the json data is pulled instantly looks like seInterval is adding lag to display the result both in tabular data display or google gauge

am I doing some thing wrong in the code

```
var url = 'http://example.com/json';
var sensorData;

function removeTable(id)
  {
      var tbl = document.getElementById(id);
      if(tbl) tbl.parentNode.removeChild(tbl);
  }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  if (jscd.mobile){
    removeTable("gaugeTable")
    document.getElementById("gaugeTable").innerHTML = "";
  }
}, false);

(function (window) {
    {
        var unknown = '-';
        // browser
        var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
        // mobile version
        var mobile = /Mobile|mini|Fennec|Android|iP(ad|od|hone)/.test(nVer);
    }
    window.jscd = {

        mobile: mobile,

    };
}(this));




$(window).load(function(){
   setInterval(function() {
   jQuery.support.cors = true;
if (jscd.mobile){
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
         format: 'json'
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
},
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(sensorData) {
        // set the sensor data pulled from arduino to global variable sensorData


             var tempHumidData = sensorData.arduino;
            renderHTML(tempHumidData);

      },

      type: 'GET'
   });
 }
}, 10000);
});



function renderHTML(data)
{
  if (data){
   var sensorDataContainer = document.getElementById("displaySensorData");
   var htmlString = "<table id='headTable' style='width:100%'><tr><th>Location</th><th>Temperature</th><th>Humidity</th></tr>";
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      htmlString += "<tr align='center'><td>"+ data[i].location + "</td><td>" + data[i].temperatureInC + "&deg;C/ " + data[i].temperatureInF + "&deg;F </td> <td> " + data[i].humidity + "%</td></tr>";
   }
   htmlString += "</table>"
   // sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
   sensorDataContainer.innerHTML = htmlString;
   }
}

//------------- Google Gauge -------------------//

// global variables
var chart, humidityChart, data, humidityData;
// maximum value for the gauge
var max_gauge_value = 70;
// name of the gauge
var gauge_name = 'Temperature';
var outTemp, drwngRomTemp, outHumidity, drwRomHumid;

var hoptions = {
animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'inAndOut'
    },
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
  yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
  minorTicks: 5
};

// load the google gauge visualization
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['gauge']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(initChart);

// display the data
function displayData(outTemp, drwngRomTemp, outHumidity, drwRomHumid) {
    chart.draw(data, options);
    data.setValue(0, 0, gauge_name);
    data.setValue(0, 1, outTemp);
    data.setValue(1, 0, gauge_name);
    data.setValue(1, 1, drwngRomTemp);
    humidityChart.draw(humidityData, hoptions);
    humidityData.setValue(0, 0, "Humidity");
    humidityData.setValue(0, 1, outHumidity);
    humidityData.setValue(1, 0, "Humidity");
    humidityData.setValue(1, 1, drwRomHumid);
    removeTable("pullingDataMsg")
}

// load the data
function loadData() {
      // get the data from arduino

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
         format: 'json'
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    },
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(sensorData) {
        // set the sensor data pulled from arduino to global variable sensorData
          // get the data point
          outTemp = sensorData.arduino[0].temperatureInC;
          drwngRomTemp = sensorData.arduino[1].temperatureInC;
          outHumidity = sensorData.arduino[0].humidity;
          drwRomHumid = sensorData.arduino[1].humidity;
      displayData(outTemp, drwngRomTemp, outHumidity, drwRomHumid);
      },

      type: 'GET'
   });
  }

  // initialize the chart
  function initChart() {
    var initTempData = {
              "cols": [
                {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                {"id":"","label":"Temperature","pattern":"","type":"number"}
              ],
              "rows": [
                {"c":[{"v":"Temperature","f":null},{"v":-20,"f":null}]},
                {"c":[{"v":"Temperature","f":null},{"v":-20,"f":null}]}
              ]
            };

    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(initTempData);



    options = { 
      greenFrom: 10,
      greenTo: 29,
      redFrom: 41,
      redTo: 70,
      yellowFrom:30,
      yellowTo: 40,
      majorTicks : ['-10', '0', '10','20','30','40','50', '60', ''],
      minorTicks: 5 ,
      animation:{
              duration: 1000,
              easing: 'inAndOut'
            },
      min: -20,
      max: 70,
      greenColor: '#CCFFCC',
      yellowColor: '#FFFFCC',
      redColor: '#F78181'
    };

    chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));

    var initHumidData = {
              "cols": [
                {"id":"","label":"Label","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                {"id":"","label":"Humidity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
              ],
              "rows": [
                {"c":[{"v":"Humidity","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]},
                {"c":[{"v":"Humidity","f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}]}
              ]
            };


    humidityData = new google.visualization.DataTable(initHumidData);

    humidityChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('humidity_gauge_div'));


    //displayData(0, 0, 0, 0);
    loadData();

    // load new data every 10 seconds
    setInterval('loadData()', 5000);
  }
```

Comment: Copy your error message here please.

Comment: `sensorData = sensorData;` this line is so bad...

Comment: the error is just that *uncaught exception : out of memory*  in the console.